# Slick Slider - Change text color with dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a quote slider. I'm looking to add the active class that the Slick Slider dots use to custom text (names/locations) that correspond with the quote being displayed. So when quote one shows, the first dot is highlighted and the name and location that corresponds with the quote is also highlighted. When quote two shows, name and location and dot dot two are highlighted and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the slick dots active element.

```
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
 // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, hope it will work for you as well.
Add this below code into your css file :

```
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    color:White !important;
```